# Evaluating Sum of $\dfrac{i}{(-x)^i}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, power-series, divergent-series

I would like to ask if the expression below can be simplified using standard summation properties? Or should I dive into much deeper concepts like the power series? Thank you.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{i}{(-x)^i}$$

Comment: I would start with [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bi%2F(-x)%5Ei,%7Bi,1,n-1%7D%5D). When you see the answer, it may help figure out how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{(-x)^i}
&= \sum_{i=2}^{n-1}(i-1)(-x)^{-i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-x)^{-i} = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}(-x)^{-i+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-x)^{-i}\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\left(-\frac 1 x\right)^{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(-\frac 1x\right)^{i}
\end{align*}